# Lists and Function Arguments

Tags: python

```
>>> def duplicate(l):
...     l = l + l
...
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> duplicate(l1)
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3]
```

I believe the function above duplicates the list. But why is the result not `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @StevieG: no, the same thing would happen outside of the function: `l = l1 + l1` would still leave `l1` unchanged.

Comment: As an aside, using a single lowercase L (l) is just asking for trouble with confusion with a one (1)

Answer (score 4):

Concatenation of two list objects (as you do with `l + l`) always creates a *new list object*. In your function you then assign that new list object back to the *local* variable `l`, which is independent of the global reference `l1`. The original list object is not affected because only the contents of the list were copied.

If you wanted to alter the list object in place, you need to extend `l` with itself:

```
def duplicate(l):
    l.extend(l)
```

`list.extend()` copies all elements from the list you pass in and adds them to the end of the list object you called it on. Passing in the list itself is safe; it'll only copy the original elements.

Demo:

```
>>> def duplicate(l):
...     l.extend(l)
...
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> duplicate(l1)
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you! I am confused by "l + l creates a new list object". When we call duplicate(l1), then the function body( l1=l1+l1) will be executed, and why l1 is a new list object ?

Comment: Because `+` concatenation on a list object always creates a new list instance.